# Hot corner black screens and throws me to login screen?

Tags: compiz, unity-tweak-tool

This makes no sense. I bind it to top-right corner. If I choose it(to expose windows), it throws me out to my login screen and closes down all my programs?

The heck? I tried both with Unity Tweak Tool and Compizconfig, both of them would reset on reboot, but now it's completely screwed.

Comment: Do you mean expose windows, or "Initiate Windows Picker" in CompizConfig? I noticed recently that the top-left corner binding that I had is no more working, to spread all windows like clicking "Super + w"